# How do I initialise store in-app-purchase?

Tags: 7, javascript

I am experimenting with [DrupalGap](http://drupalgap.org/) and it's great what it already provides out of the box. One feature that module  is missing is in-app-purchasing (where payments go via Apple).

Cordova provides a great cross-platform plugin with some good documentation.

This is a [full example](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-purchase-demo/blob/master/www/js/index.js), and this [a minimal example](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/doc/minimal-example.js).

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', initializeStore, false);

function initializeStore() {

// Let's set a pretty high verbosity level, so that we see a lot of stuff
// in the console (reassuring us that something is happening).
store.verbosity = store.INFO;

// We register a dummy product. It's ok, it shouldn't
// prevent the store "ready" event from firing.
store.register({
    id:    "com.example.app.inappid1",
    alias: "100 coins",
    type:  store.CONSUMABLE
});

// When every goes as expected, it's time to celebrate!
// The "ready" event should be welcomed with music and fireworks,
// go ask your boss about it! (just in case)
store.ready(function() {
    console.log("\\o/ STORE READY \\o/");
});

// After we've done our setup, we tell the store to do
// it's first refresh. Nothing will happen if we do not call store.refresh()
store.refresh();
}
```

**How can I add the document.Eventlistener and the initalization function within DrupalGap?**

The cordova plugin is installed, the products are set up in iTunes and the provisioning profiles with in-app-purchasing feature are created.
I have created a custom module with a menu link in DrupalGap where the user can make his in-app-purchases.

**UPDATE:**

This code works (Thanks, Tyler) and connects to the iTunesConnect store and pulls the requested/registered products.

You don't need a sandbox user to pull the products.

You do need to submit Apple the 3 legal documents even if you only use a development provisioning profile. It takes a few hours until the docs are submitted.

Here is another useful link (when your product is invalid): http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

```
/**
 * Implements hook_deviceready().
 */
function my_module_deviceready() {
// Let's set a pretty high verbosity level, so that we see a lot of stuff in the console (reassuring us that something is happening).
//store.verbosity = store.INFO;
store.verbosity = store.DEBUG; // even higher

// We register/request a product:
store.register({
id: "130points", // this is id of your product in iTunesConnect
alias: "130points_alias",
type: store.CONSUMABLE
});
// When every goes as expected, it's time to celebrate!
// The "ready" event should be welcomed with music and fireworks,
// go ask your boss about it! (just in case)
store.ready(function() {
console.log("\\o/ STORE READY \\o/");
});
// When any product gets updated, refresh the HTML.
store.when("product").updated(function (product_item) {
console.log("product_item: " + JSON.stringify(product_item)); // this is the response from iTunesConnect
});
// After we've done our setup, we tell the store to do it's first refresh. Nothing will happen if we do not call 
store.refresh();
return true; // Let DrupalGap know it is OK to continue.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [DrupalGap Custom Module](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Modules/Create_a_Custom_Module), you'll use [hook_deviceready()](http://api.drupalgap.org/global.html#hook_deviceready):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_deviceready().
 */
function my_module_deviceready() {
  // Place your initializeStore function's code here...

  return true; // Let DrupalGap know it is OK to continue.
}
```